# Preserve aspect ratio when pasting width or height in Inkscape

Tags: copy-paste, vector-graphics, aspect-ratio, inkscape, drawing

I'm frequently using the paste size feature in Inkscape to ensure that several objects have the same size. But sometimes I want to just ensure that a new object has the same height as a old object but I want to preserve the aspect of the new object.

Basically I need a paste height and keep aspect feature. Is this possible somehow?

Or do I need to continue manually placing the two object on top of each other, and scale the height to the same manually?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use the "Aspect Ratio Lock" Button. This is found on the main tool bar. It is an orange/yellow padlock sitting next to the X: Y: and W: boxes used to adjust position and width.

If you press the lock button it will lock lock the aspect ratio when you paste either width or height